# How to remove ssh Key from github account and commit using http

Tags: git, github

I want to remove the settings of the SSH key and want to behave my account to accept commit normally from HTTPS.

Accidentally I configured the key settings.

Now when I need to push the new code it makes so much trouble for me.

I don't want to push using the SSH key instead to push with HTTP.

I have seen many question none of that helps me to get rid of my problem no one tell how to reset the  setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the SSH, you have to remove the SSH Key that you have added when enabling it.

Go to: `Settings > SSH and GPG Keys` and delete that SSH key that you don't want to use now.

After that:

You have to change the remote url to `HTTPS` one by this command if you have upstream as remote repository:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <HTTPS URL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you clone a repository, you use the HTTPS URL and not the SSH URL, By clicking on the "**Use HTTPS**" button in the **top right** of the GitHub clone dialog:

[image]

This will make it change to look like this:

[image]

Copy this URL, rather than the SSH one.

If you already cloned the repository with SSH, you can run this command inside the repository:

`git remote set-url origin <paste the HTTPS URL here>`

This will change the URL of the `origin` remote to the new, HTTPS URL which handles authentication via username/password rather than SSH keys